# Initialize preferences from XML in the main Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences

My problem is that when I start application and user didn't open my `PreferenceActivity` so when I retrieve them don't get any default values defined in my preference.xml file.

preference.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="applicationPreference" android:title="@string/config"
    >
    <ListPreference
            android:key="pref1"
            android:defaultValue="default"
            android:title="Title"
            android:summary="Summary"
            android:entries="@array/entry_names"
            android:entryValues="@array/entry_values"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title"
    />                  
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Snippet from my main Activity (`onCreate` method):

```
    SharedPreferences appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);        
    String pref1 = appPreferences.getString("pref1", null);
```

In result I end up with a `null` value.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

In `onCreate()` of your main `Activity` just call [the `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues(android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean)).

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, false);
```

This will read your `preference.xml` file and set the default values defined there.  Setting the `readAgain` argument to `false` means this will only set the default values if this method has never been called in the past so you don't need to worry about overriding the user's settings each time your `Activity` is created.

Comment: but anyone have the sample or template for this perference.xml for reference?

Comment: You saved my day! Been looking for 3 hours at the null value, at 3 'o clock at night in an airport wit tethering wifi. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave Webb This does not work for string preferences.

Comment: Setting `readAgain` to true has nothing to do with overriding the user's settings. From the Javadoc: _Note: this will NOT reset preferences back to their default values._

Comment: How does this work when new settings are added in updates? They won't be initialized, will they?

Comment: How to reset the specific key to its default value.

Answer (score 14):

I'll be brief. :)

**strings.xml** (actually I have **prefs.xml** exclusively for preferences):

```
<string name="pref_mypref_key">mypref</string>
<string name="pref_mypref_default">blah</string>
```

**preferences.xml**:

```
android:key="@string/pref_mypref_key"
android:defaultValue="@string/pref_mypref_default"
```

**MyActivity.java**:

```
String myprefVal = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_mypref_key), getString(R.string.pref_mypref_default));
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually is answer to my another question about where to store preference keys :) If I'll be able to combine it with best answer to this question it will be great!

Comment: Apparently, in this example, this line would appear in `MyActivity.java` before the assignment of `myprefVal`: `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

Comment: This works, but should this really be necessary?

Answer (score 8):

Your call to `getString()` has `null` as the second parameter. Change that to be the default value you want.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. +1. However, to achieve what the OP wanted, the PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues() is the solution.