# Android Shared Preferences Initialization

Tags: android, initialization, sharedpreferences

It is often nice to have some default values in Shared Preferences to begin with.  Is there  a good way to initialize them from an xml file or property file? Looking for the best way to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Preferences: How to load the default values when the user hasn't used the preferences-screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691772/android-preferences-how-to-load-the-default-values-when-the-user-hasnt-used-th)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the answer in this question:

[Android Preferences: How to load the default values when the user hasn't used the preferences-screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691772/android-preferences-how-to-load-the-default-values-when-the-user-hasnt-used-the)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Make sure default values are applied.  In a real app, you would
        // want this in a shared function that is used to retrieve the
        // SharedPreferences wherever they are needed.
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(),
                R.xml.advanced_preferences, false);

}
```