# Default values from the preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691772/android-preferences-how-to-load-the-default-values-when-the-user-hasnt-used-the) I can load the default values from my XML-preference file right at the beginning. But when I check the keys of my settings I see, that my R.xml.preferences is not read at all. Perhaps this will be done the first time, the user launches a PreferenceScreen. Is there a solution reg. *How to retrieve the values when user launches the app the first time?* Cause the link doesn't help.

Is there some kind of difference when to launch it? But neither Context nor Application brought a change. Or do I need to remove something from the dirs, cause the R.xml.preferences are not installed in the SharedPreferences-Dir from where the content is retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in onCreate method of your main activity

```
// Make sure default values are applied.  In a real app, you would
        // want this in a shared function that is used to retrieve the
        // SharedPreferences wherever they are needed.
       PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.advanced_preferences, false);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragmented_preferences);
```

Comment: For the first - please see the other comment. For the second method, I cannot find them in the `Activty`, but in the `PreferenceActivity` and this would imply to use the PreferenceScreen in advance. But I want to load the preferences for the preference-xml-file in advance prior to user-interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Use application class for this:

```
public class App extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.prefs, false);
    }

}
```

And add it to manifest:

```
 <application
            android:name=".App"
```

Comment: But this only loads the SharedPrefs which are already used resp. set. I mean they are not retrieved from the build-xml-file but from the xml-which is obviously saved after editing. If I retrieve the settings via `SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);` then I don't get any default-values from the prefs-file.

Comment: @LeO You have to tell android where to get preferences from. `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` will load empty file if you don't load it before hand. Also, `build.xml` file in project is for Ant, not for app preferences.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm lost with your response. It makes sense, but actually I have no clue how to retrieve them. IFFF my (default)preferences are stored in the _R.xml.prefs_ how to retrieve them from there? The `setDefaultValues()`-method might be handy, but I have no clue, how to retrieve/access now the values?