# Resetting a specific EditText Preference after onClick

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-preferences, android-xml

So I have been stuck on this problem for awhile, I cannot reset an edittext to its default. I have only int inputs for a few edittexts and I need each one to be within a different int range.Right now I am able to check if the value entered is within the range and display an alert dialog if not, but i cannot figure out how to reset the edittext to its default value, set in the preference xml. I am able to reset all my preference values but I do not want to do that I just want to reset the specific one, the one that is wrong.

Comment: did this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2877795/2188682

Comment: I saw that it resets all preference values. I need to reset to default just one, it is identified by a check method.@ChristianR.

Comment: Can you show the code where you verify if the entered values match the criteria? Basically, the relevant code.