# Difference between preference default value in xml and code

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

When i set the the default value for a preference in the xml attribute `android:defaultValue`, why do I still have to define a default value in code when accessing a preference using for example `sharedPrefs.getString("foo", DEFAULT_STRING)`? This seems redundant to me.

Comment: Because it  **Returns: the preference value if it exists, or defValue. Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not a String.**

Answer (score 0):

This is because two different mechanisms are used. I think [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691772/android-preferences-how-to-load-the-default-values-when-the-user-hasnt-used-th) can help.