# Java - Android PreferenceFragment save and load preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, preferencefragment

I created a PreferenceFragment. How I can save the changed preferences and load by app restart? My second question: How I can get preference values from another class?

My PrefsActivity

```
public class PrefsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static PrefsFragment mPrefsFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mPrefsFragment = new PrefsFragment();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mPrefsFragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

And my PrefsFragment

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is better to ask separate questions as multiple questions instead of combining them, so we can more accurately answer them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read preferences, use the following in your other Activity:

```
SharedPreferences spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Then, to read the preferences, use:

```
String sEmailAddr = spref.getString("email", "");
```

The first argument is the 'key' you want to get, and this should be defined in the XML file of the perferences (`R.xml.settings` in your case). The second argument is what should be returned when there is no such key.

Other types of Preference work in a similar way. To get a boolean, set by a checkbox:

```
boolean showEmail = spref.getBoolean("show_emails", true);
```

There is no need to explicitly save or load the preferences, as this is done automatically.

There is more information in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). You should also initialize the default values for the preferences, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691772/android-preferences-how-to-load-the-default-values-when-the-user-hasnt-used-th).

Comment: "There is no need to explicitly save or load the preferences, as this is done automatically."

As far as I know you have to call commit() or apply() to save preferences.